# Alterar formato de data no form do rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Sei que existe como editar na localização, para a passar para o formato brasileiro. Mas não sei a sintaxe para mudar o formato no form:

```
  <div class="field">
    <p> Garantia </p>
    <%= f.date_select :guarantee %>
  </div>
```

Comment: Olha se pode te ajudar. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449955/rails-date-format-in-a-text-field

Comment: Acho que isso é uma questão do HTML, não é? Qual o tipo de input que o `date_select` gera?

Comment: Conseguiu resolver o problema?

Comment: @ygorbr Conseguiu resolver o problema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coloque em seu `config/application.rb`

```
 Time::DATE_FORMATS[:default] = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M"
 Date::DATE_FORMATS[:default] = "%d/%m/%Y"
```

Que a formatação de todas a datas do sistema vão para o padrão brasileiro.

Comment: Obrigado Luiz Carvalho. Problema resolvido.

Answer (score -1):

Estava procurando sobre datas e caí aqui, para você usar na o formato longo brasileiro com o I18n é bem interessante:

```
I18n.l(Time.now, format: "%d de %B de %Y") # 27 de fevereiro de 2021
```